# Pandas row count using pd.pivot_table Without Values parameter

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

How can I get row count using Pandas pivot table without passing anything to values parameter? If I do as below, the pivot table produced will have row count for columns Age and Name, which does not feel clean.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

visitor = [['Jack', 34, 'Australia', 'Sydney'] ,
             ['Riti', 30, 'India', 'Delhi' ] ,
             ['Aadi', 16, 'United States', 'New York'], 
             ['Mary', 22, 'United States', 'New York'], 
             ['Doug', 13, 'United States', 'Los Angeles'],
             ['Chad', 15, 'Australia', 'Sydney'],
             ['Alba', 32, 'United Kingdom', 'London']]

df = pd.DataFrame(visitor, columns=['Name','Age','Country', 'City'])

pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Country', 'City'], aggfunc='count')
```

Output dataframe

```
                                Age    Name
Country           City           
Australia         Sydney         2      2
India             Delhi          1      1
United Kingdom    London         1      1
United States     Los Angeles    1      1
                  New York       2      2
```

In SQL, I could

```
SELECT country, city, count(*) FROM visitor GROUP BY country, city
```

and no unnecessary columns are added to output table, which feels cleaner.

```
                                count   
Country           City           
Australia         Sydney         2  
India             Delhi          1 
United Kingdom    London         1 
United States     Los Angeles    1 
United States     New York       2
```

Comment: I like the `groupby` answer posted below, but if you want something along what you were doing you could change `index` to `columns` like this: `pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['Country', 'City'], aggfunc='count')['Name']`

Answer (score 1):

Just do [pd.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
res = df.groupby(['Country','City'],as_index=False)['Name'].count().rename(columns={"Name":"Count"})
print(res)
```

```
    Country         City    Count
0   Australia       Sydney      2
1   India           Delhi       1
2   United Kingdom  London      1
3   United States   Los Angeles 1
4   United States   New York    2
```